# chromatic number edge coloring of cartesian graphs

Tags: graph-theory

**Why edg-chromatic number of Cartesian product of two graph equal maximum degree of Cartesian product G and H?**
for example G and k2

Comment: Your question asks about **chromatic number** but the title mentions **edge coloring**. Do you really mean chromatic number, or do you mean edge-chromatic number (chromatic index)?

Comment: The graph $K_3\square K_1$ is the Cartesian product of two graphs, but the chromatic number and the edge-chromatic number are both equal to $3$, while the maximum degree is equal to $2$. Please clarify.